# Grant Access Hierarchy

Tags: account, role-hierarchy, hierarchy, sharerecord

I have a query on Grant access hierarchy and sharing rule.

I have in my system Accounts being shared to Users through Account Share , Group and Territory. Now, I have A1 account shared to T1 territory through Account Share. User U1 is aligned to T1 territory. But A1 has no sharing to U2, the Manager of U1 by both Role and Territory. Still U2 is able to view the account.  Account object has OWD private and Grant Access through hierarchy as checked. Now, even if I change the role of U2, A1 is visible to U2.

Can someone please let me know by which procedure U2 is able to view A1 here?

Comment: Since U2 is manager of U1 and U1 is having access to Account and Territory. Also Grant Access through Hierarchy is checked. That could be the reason. I guess.